# TypeError on Learn Python Playground

Tags: python

New to coding, started writing python yesterday, I’m trying to make a code for the area of a circle.

```
pi=3.14 
radius=input("enter radius here") 
print("area="+str(pi*(radius**2)))
```

When I ran the code, it gave me a type error saying that `unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int.'` 
I don’t understand what this means, can someone help me write it?

Comment: Complete shot in the dark: the tutorial says something like `x = input("Enter a number"); print(x**2)`. This code works in Python 2.7, but not in Python 3, because `input` behaves differently across versions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code you have. Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Thank you Johnny. I’m unable to post the code, as I’m uncertain of how to indent the code.

Comment: Come now, that isn't a good reason. Just Google "formatting stackoverflow question"

Comment: pi=3.14
radius=input("enter radius here")
print("area="+str(pi*(radius**2)))

Comment: You must convert the user input to a number. See this question for suggestions of how to handle invalid input. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response